# twitter api 1.1 search

Tags: twitter, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfhttp

I am using Coldfusion 9 with Twitter4J authorization for twitter authorization. I have authenticated and am running a very simple coldfusion script to try and get a result from a twitter search get. The code I am using is:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145&result_type=mixed&count=4" result="result">

<cfdump var="#result#"><cfabort>
```

The error that I receive is: 400 Bad request Any thoughts in what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your firewall blocking you?

Comment: I can get to twitter at the domain without any issue. I also can login through twitter on my phone and I get the same error.

Comment: what happens if you properly encode your query string parameters?

Comment: well.. I feared that I may have had an encoding issue so I specifically used the twitter api example URL as detailed here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: I also tried `"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames"` and get the same error.

Comment: are you passing your headers properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a certificate problem. You could use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) with the `--insecure` option  to bypass any certificate problem. Or [Import the certificate](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html) into the ColdFusion certificate store.